# Why is datamapper trying to re-save my relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datamapper

I have a model called User who has a many to many relationship with Interests.

Lets say the join table looks like this:

```
User ID | Interest ID
---------------------
   5    |      1
```

When I edit this user's name (for example) and call `user.save`, it fails.

The reason it fails is because datamapper (AFAIK) is trying to re-save the relationship with Interests. The error I get is:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_interests_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, interest_id)=(5, 1) already exists.
```

Has anyone experienced this? Anybody know a solution? Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE

The User model looks lik:

```
class User    
  include DataMapper::Resource

  has n, :interests, :through => Resource, :constraint => :skip  
end
```

Whereas the Interest model looks like:

```
class Interest
  include DataMapper::Resource

  has n, :users, :through => Resource, :constraint => :skip
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the code to run put the `user.save` in a

```
begin
  user.save
rescue
  # DO STH MEANINGLESS
end
```

If you really want to solve the problem you should be a little more verbous. Is this a HABTM association? The association specification would also be helpfull.

Comment: I've added the model relationship specification - its a many to many relationship as mentioned in the original question. Thanks!